# Standard Paypal IPN for mobile

Tags: mobile, paypal, paypal-ipn

Does the standard payment paypal [IPN](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_formbasics) also work for mobile devices?

I have tried with standard form (on android) and there is a redirection to:

https://mobile.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_express-checkout-mobile&token=xxxxxxx

Answer (score 1):

IPN is a server-side implement. It has nothing to do with the client - IPN means "Instant Payment Notification" - meaning your *server* is notified when a payment is made.

The client (whatever it may be) checks out as normal on PayPal, and then PayPal's servers talk to your server URI and POST it a message with info about the payment that was just made. The client is not involved in any way, shape, or form in the IPN process (other than the IPN URI being optionally in the payment form's payload from your site to PayPal, but this is basic HTML form and nothing IPN-specific or (non-)mobile exclusive).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So a customer can still purchase by phone with Website Payments Standard Forms and ipn works as usual.

Comment: Yes. Done it myself as both a customer and a developer many times.